# ps -ax shows me a "rack" process. Is this normal?

Tags: ruby, linux, sinatra, rack

I run a webpage using the Ruby web-framework Sinatra on my Ubuntu server. Today I looked to my processes and found these two lines:

```
30129 ?        S      0:00 Passenger ApplicationSpawner: /var/www/bla.com                                                    
30139 ?        S      0:00 Rack: /var/www/bla.com
```

I never noticed these before. Are these normal, or should I be concerned?

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find, Rack is used by Sinatra:

> Sinatra rides on Rack, a minimal standard interface for Ruby web frameworks.

from http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro

Answer (score 1):

It should be normal. Check out what [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) is. Killing that process could risk your webpage functionality, so don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal. Passenger is your webserver, and Rack is the middleware between your server and Sinatra framework.